# Why Does HTML.TextArea require an @ before it?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

The below doesn't seem to work unless @ is before the @Html. Why is that?

```
@{
 if (DescriptionIsFieldReadOnly) {
                            Html.TextArea("description-edit", Model.Requisition.ReqHdr.Description, new { @Readonly = "readonly" });
                        }
                        else {
                            Html.TextArea("description-edit", Model.Requisition.ReqHdr.Description);
                        } 
}
```

Comment: it same as <%= %>，it need a "=" and razor need a "@";without "@" like <%%>,only call method,not write to response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.TextArea(...)` returns an `IHtmlString` with the HTML code you want.

If you call it as a normal function, you don't actually do anything with that return value, so nothing happens.

Using `@` turns it into a Razor expression that prints its value to the page.

Incidentally, that isn't a statement, so it should not have a semicolon.

Comment: If i do a return Html.textARea(...) instead of @Html.TextArea... will it work?

Comment: Razor templates cannot return anything

Answer (score 0):

You add code to a page using the @ character.
The @: sequence indicates that  the line of content that follows should be treated as a content block.

Html.TextArea returns a string and to render it using razor view engine,you need to use @ at its start like you asked @Html.TextArea